# SSH Tunnel in Python

Tags: python, linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have 3 Ubuntu machine, Machine 2 is having two Ethernet port ie its having two IPs of two different sub-net. Machine 1 can ping to machine 2 and machine 2 can ping to machine 3 as well as machine 1. But machine 1 can not ping to machine 3 and vice versa. Following are the IPs of the machines:

1. Machine 1 IP : 192.168.0.10
2. Machine 2 eth0 IP : 192.168.0.20
3. Machine 2 eth1 IP : 192.168.167.10
4. Machine 3 IP : 192.168.167.20

I can ssh from Machine 1 to Machine 2 using user name and password of machine 2.
I can ssh from Machine 2 to Machine 3 using user name of machine 3 and a key provided for machine 3.

Now I would like to run a python script on machine 1 and I want to run a command on machine 3 (like uname -a) using this python script.

I used below code to do this:

```
import paramiko
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("machineKey.key", password='Password')

with SSHTunnelForwarder(
("192.168.0.20", 22),             #Machine 2 IP
ssh_username="user",              #Machine 2's user name
ssh_password="password",          #Machine 2's password
ssh_pkey=key,                     #Machine 3's key (required for authentication)
remote_bind_address=("192.168.167.20", 22),        #Machine 3's IP
) as tunnel:

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('0.0.0.0', 22)
print (client.exec_command("uname -a"))
client.close()
print('FINISH!')
```

When I ran this I got following error:

```
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:starting thread (client mode): 0xb6de7b8cL
INFO:paramiko.transport:Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_6.6.1p1)
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Ciphers agreed: local=aes128-ctr, remote=aes128-    ctr
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:using kex diffie-hellman-group1-sha1; server key     type ssh-rsa; cipher: local aes128-ctr, remote aes128-ctr; mac: local     hmac-sha1, remote hmac-sha1; compression: local none, remote none
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Switch to new keys ...
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Attempting public-key auth...
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is OK
INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (publickey) failed.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:EOF in transport thread
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:starting thread (client mode): 0xb6de7b2cL
INFO:paramiko.transport:Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_6.6.1p1)
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Ciphers agreed: local=aes128-ctr, remote=aes128-ctr
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:using kex diffie-hellman-group1-sha1; server key type ssh-rsa; cipher: local aes128-ctr, remote aes128-ctr; mac: local     hmac-sha1, remote hmac-sha1; compression: local none, remote none
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Switch to new keys ...
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Attempting password auth...
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is OK
INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (password) successful!
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:EOF in transport thread
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tunnelTest.py", line 37, in <module>
    client.connect("127.0.0.1", 2947, username = "root", pkey = key)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 300, in connect
    retry_on_signal(lambda: sock.connect(addr))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/util.py", line 278, in retry_on_signal
    return function()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 300, in <lambda>
    retry_on_signal(lambda: sock.connect(addr))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Can anyone suggest what I changes I have to do to make it run?
Thanks

Comment: I cannot understand what your script tries to do. My advice is to avoid mixing the complexity levels: first setup a tunnel with direct ssh commands, and only when you have done it, convert all to Python and paramiko.

Comment: I am able to do direct ssh (from terminal) to machine 3 from machine 1.
    1:SSH to machine 2 from machine 1.
    2.Add key to the terminal using ssh-add key command.
    3.Then ssh to machine 3.
    4.And I got the console of machine 3.

Comment: That is not an ssh tunnel. You are just opening a new ssh connection from a relay. Why do not you try to mimic it directly?

Comment: can you please give me few links or some sample code. Because I am new to python.